# Android Firebase Query not fetching updated data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView of custom objects that pull data from Firebase. In each item, there is a "likeButton" to increment the likes of a certain comment. Since RecyclerViews have no onItemClickListener methods, I have declared this in the adapter class's inner ViewHolder class:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private TextView username, chirp, time, likeCount;
        private ImageButton likeButton;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            username = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_feed_item_username);
            chirp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_feed_item_chirp);
            time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_feed_item_time);
            likeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_feed_item_like_count);
            likeButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_feed_item_like_button);

            //set click listener for likeButton
            likeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            //set click listener for whole view, which will take them to the details activity
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        //define click listener for likeButton
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == likeButton.getId()){
                //access Firebase
                final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chirps");

                //query for this specific chirp
                Query query = reference.orderByChild("chirp").equalTo(chirp.getText().toString());
                query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            //convert the dataSnapshot
                            HomeFeedItem queryResult = dataSnapshot.getValue(HomeFeedItem.class);
                            //here, it keeps printing out 0
                            System.out.println(queryResult.getLikeCount());

                            //increment it
                            int likeCountUpdated = queryResult.getLikeCount() + 1;

                            //update the likeCount textview
                            likeCount.setText(String.valueOf(likeCountUpdated));

                            //update the likeCount in the database
                            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                reference.child(child.getKey()).child("likeCount").setValue(likeCountUpdated);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Ahh, you liked "+username.getText().toString()+"'s chirp!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Going to chirp activity...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

So the idea is that whenever a user clicks the likeButton, it increments the class's likeCount and updates Firebase. However, this works only the first time I click the likeButton - both the likeCount textView and Firebase are incremented by one, but only the first time, in other words. In my SOUT statement, for subsequent clicks, it keeps saying likeCount is 0, so it looks like it's querying the very first instance of the HomeFeedItem, not the updated Firebase object. And ideas on how to make it query the updated Firebase object each time I click it, and not just fetch the original object? Thanks!

Comment: try to use query.addChildEventListener instead query.addValueEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So your code needs to handle that list, by looping over the children of the snapshot:

```
Query query = reference.orderByChild("chirp").equalTo(chirp.getText().toString());
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //convert the dataSnapshot
            HomeFeedItem queryResult = childSnapshot.getValue(HomeFeedItem.class);
            //here, it keeps printing out 0
            System.out.println(queryResult.getLikeCount());

            //increment it
            int likeCountUpdated = queryResult.getLikeCount() + 1;

            //update the likeCount textview
            likeCount.setText(String.valueOf(likeCountUpdated));
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Turns out I had to loop through childSnapshot.getChildren() as well, and use `if(chirpField.getKey().equals("likeCount")){` instead of converting it to a HomeFeedItem. But thank you for the point in the right direction! As a side note, were you the man in the Firebase in a Weekend video from Google and Udacity?

Comment: Aha. I wasn't really sure of what's going on deeper in the code, but was quite certain you were missing the outermost loop. Good to hear you got it sorted. And yes: I was one of the barbecuing men in those videos. :-)